# Symfony 5.2.11: Problem with creating Custom Access Decision Manager

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I am trying to create a Custom Access Decision Manager by implementing `AccessDecisionManagerInterface` on Symfony 5.2.

Symfony recognizes the decision manager and instantiate it, but it doesn't pass Voters array to decision manager. So it can't collect votes, however the default decision manager works fine. I have followed the information provided on Symfony website. I have also copied the decision manager file to my App\Security and just changed the class+file name but it didn't work. Adding the custom decision manager to `service.yml` didn't help too.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Any chance to fix it?

**UPDATE #1**

With reference to the issue https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/41123

I encountered this issue with different symptoms!

Although I knew the service is automatically registered but I did this in **service.yml**:

```
    App\Security\SpecialAccessDecisionManager:
        class: App\Security\SpecialAccessDecisionManager  
        autowire: false
        autoconfigure: false
        public: false
```

then I added decision manager to **security.yml**:

```
security:
    access_decision_manager:
        service: App\Security\SpecialAccessDecisionManager
```

As you can see below, arguments haven't been passed to the decision manager:

```
[root@dev7 rouzonline.test]# bin/console debug:container debug.security.access.decision_manager.inner --show-arguments                            

 // This service is a private alias for the service                                                                     
 // App\Security\SpecialAccessDecisionManager                                                                           

Information for Service "App\Security\SpecialAccessDecisionManager"
===================================================================

 Description of SpecialAccessDecisionManager

 ---------------- ------------------------------------------- 
  Option           Value                                      
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------- 
  Service ID       App\Security\SpecialAccessDecisionManager  
  Class            App\Security\SpecialAccessDecisionManager  
  Tags             -                                          
  Public           no                                         
  Synthetic        no                                         
  Lazy             no                                         
  Shared           yes                                        
  Abstract         no                                         
  Autowired        no                                         
  Autoconfigured   no                                         
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------- 


 ! [NOTE] The "debug.security.access.decision_manager.inner" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the      
 !        container was compiled.                                                                                       

[root@dev7 rouzonline.test]#
```

When I use default **AccessDecisionManager** voters are passed. I need to implement special authorization so I need to create my own decision manager. By the way, my decision manager implements **AccessDecisionManagerInterface**

I also checked `\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\Compiler\AddSecurityVotersPass->process()` , it is not being called when my decision manager is set.

**UPDATE #2**
For testing, I temporarily renamed default **AccessDecisionManager.php** and placed my decision manager, it surprisingly worked. But it is not the solution. Still looking for the correct solution.

Comment: Please, provide more details (especially all relevant code). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @DonCallisto I have updated my question with more details, I found a closed issue on GitHub similar to my case. 
As you can see arguments are not passed to the decision manager, I expect iterable list of voters along with other parameters to be passed to decision manager.
These arguments are passed when using symfony default access decision manager.

Comment: The problem is (half) with the access decision manager's design, you can replace the class but you are not really meant to. When you replace it with your own service the compiler pass can not be sure where to inject the voters. So, you are basically forced to add the voters to your service yourself, i.e. write your own compiler pass. What exactly are you trying to do? Have your own decision strategy?

Comment: The problem is that this part has not been clearly documented by Symfony. Symfony recommends to implement AccessDecisionManagerInterface, inject it as service and define it ADM. The have two voters which have to be consulted unanimously while other   default voters should be consulted with Affirmative strategy, ADM has to receive list of all voters and to be able to invoke supports() method to generate list of voters that support the queried subject. When I use my ADM, Symfony doesn't fill out arguments for ADM __construct() method and it is not documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you guys for your replies and helps, *I figured it out*.

#### Workaround

When Symfony compiles the code, it (somehow) has its own service definitions, so it doesn't get confused. I traced the code into the compiled cache and I found that it can't determine the service definitions of my ADM. So I changed my `service.yml` and defined arguments as follows:

```
    security.access.decision_manager:
        class: App\Security\SpecialAccessDecisionManager  
        arguments:
            - []
            - 'affirmative'
            - false
            - true
```

Inside `vendor/symfony/security-bundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/AddSecurityVotersPass.php` I found that there is argument replacement which enumerates service arguments by number, that is why I added unnamed service arguments.

```
        $container->getDefinition('security.access.decision_manager')
            ->replaceArgument(0, new IteratorArgument($voterServices));
    }
```

The traces showed that Symfony collects all voters correctly up to this point, so it is not needed to manage dependencies manually.

By using this service.yml, I didn't need to define the `access_decision_manager` in `security.yml`.

After finding the problem, I tried to use `access_decision_manager` but it caused the same error, means it didn't receive list of voters. Then I decided to stop working on the problem as it is working for me now.

#### Conclusion

I know AccessDecisionManager is somehow a deep Symfony concept which is rarely used for common projects, but:

1. Documentation doesn't adequately cover this part
2. When a developer implements an interface and injects it to Symfony, it is supposed either to be treated exactly same as the native code or provide enough descriptive logs or details to show noncompliance
3. The method I used to fix the problem is not standard and might need modification in the future
4. Symfony misbehaves when it is processing `access_decision_manager` from `security.yml`

Probably this part of Symfony needs to be reviewed.

Comment: I'm surprised to be the only one that find it to be very useful...